# Woo-commerce Product Parent category then show child categories and then products related to child categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i am trying to show on my custom template name (Brands.php) all brands from brand category(i-e Acson,samsung,lg,eco-star etc)[image]when click on any of brand category it will show appliances related to that brand(e.g if i click samsung it will show me airconditioner,LCD's,refrigrator etc etc)[image]and in each sub-category it will show products like[image]. The product should be shown like woocommerce shop layout. Any help would be appriciated. Need effective query or woocommerce hook or filter for doing work like this.

Comment: It's unclear what exact problem you're trying to solve? What have you tried already that didn't work, or are you looking for a guide (which we can't really suggest).

Comment: I'm building woo commerce online store for electronics. i'm facing one problem that i'm unable to show sub-categories inside parent category.

Comment: <?php
$term_id = 43;
$taxonomy_name = 'product_cat';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
$id = $term->term_id;
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
$image_url = z_taxonomy_image_url( $term->term_id, NULL, TRUE );
echo '<div class="col-md-3" style="height:300px;">';
echo '<h1 class="title-heading-left" style="text-align:center"><a href="' . get_site_url() . '/brand-categories?brand='.$term->slug.'">' . $term->name . '</a></h1>';  echo '</div>';

}

?>